# bundle install error Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack": In GemFile: irwi was resolved to 0.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtualbox

please help me with this bundle install error....

> Resolving
>   dependencies...............................................................
>       Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
>         In Gemfile:
>           irwi was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
>             actionpack (>= 4.0)
>
> rails (= 3.1.4) was resolved to 3.1.4, which depends on   actionpack
>   (= 3.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

You must either update your `Rails` version (this will update your `actionpack`) or downgrade `irwi` to an old version which is compatible with `Rails 3.1.4`

I strongly recommend updating `Rails`

According to docs for `irwi` (README) and [`gemspec`](https://github.com/alno/irwi/blob/master/irwi.gemspec)

> Irwi is a Ruby on Rails 4 plugin which adds wiki functionality to your application.

it seems like it will work only with `RoR 4+`

Comment: how do i down grade coz i am using ruby v 1.9.3

Comment: how do i down grade coz i am using ruby v 1.9.3 rails v 3.1.4 and gem v 2.4.3 i am sooo new to this and have to work on an existing code written on the old version. and i keep getting errors like "The git source git://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application " and when i run bundle install i get another error

Comment: @4Tune Downgrade is a general option for errors like that, but in your particular case - you can't. The only option is to use another gem (if exists), because `irwi` asks for `Rails 4+`

Comment: oooh o thanx but how do i use another gem and which one or is it possible to upgrade my rails framewrk to 4+, is it gonna be compitable with the ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: @4Tune Rails 4+ Ruby 2.0 preferred; 1.9.3+ required. So it will be compatible with ruby 1.9.3. To see another gems probably fitting your requirements see https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wiki or https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps

Comment: i cant figure it out.. i am trying to run bundle install it keeps on saying.... fatal: unable to connect to github.com  github.com[ip address]: errno=Connection timed out...retrying git clone.....

Comment: i dnt know wat to do now

Comment: @4Tune It could be, could you please provide your Gemfile

Comment: i am strugling to find a way to copy it from VM to paste here on windows is der a way that i can just copy something from ubuntu VM to windows

Comment: here is my gemfile         source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.4'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :branch=>'3-1-stable'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'foreigner'
#postgreSql
gem 'pg'

Comment: #mysql
#gem 'mysql2'
gem 'prawn', :git=>'git://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git'
gem 'prawnto_2', :require => "prawnto"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0"
gem 'remotipart', '~> 0.4'
gem 'redis'
gem 'json',"~>1.4.6"
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'system_timer'

Comment: gem "rhoconnect-rb", '~> 0.3.2'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'irwi',  :git => 'git://github.com/alno/irwi.git'
gem 'googlecharts'
#gem "rack-ssl", "~> 1.3.2"
gem "rack-ssl"
gem "gmaps4rails", "~> 1.4.8"
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

Comment: # Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
end

Comment: thats all what is is my gem file